# How to create MSI package, which can install Windows installer itself

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

Is it possible to create MSI package, which will run without Windows installer installed in system, but first will install Windows installer itself, and then continue installing other components?

The goal is to create prerequisite package for our software, which must install some components, including some operation system service packs. We also prefer using MSI package. But it's obviously to us that our software will be installed on clean operation system. Though there will not be needed Windows installer present. Is it possible to create such prerequisite package using MSI?

Comment: Now that's chicken and egg :) I strongly doubt that's possible: if target computer doesn't have Windows Installer installed, how is it going to handle an _msi_ file?

Comment: Well, I hoped there could be way to create .exe distributive using MSI, and firstly this distributive will install Windows installer. Is there any? Or is the only way to do it is to use something else, like NSIS?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to install an .MSI package without Windows Installer already being present in the OS.

However, Windows Installer has been a native part of Windows since Windows 2000.  Are you really developing installers for Windows 95/98/NT4?  That would be the only case where there is no Windows Installer support and you'd need to install a redistributable MSI package first.

Unless you meant to say that you require a higher version of Windows Installer than is native to one of the older OSes?  (e.g. MSI 3.1 for WinXP) In that case, you'll need to bundle the .MSI redistributable for the MSI package you desire and run that first.  Sometimes a reboot is required, other times not.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

One way, you can write an application in cpp or c or any language that does not require any additional frameworks or SDKs, to check for the installer and install it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a bootstrapped with two or more msi files in it. Take look at the WiX documentation. WiX has build-in bootstrapped

Hope this helps

s